# Searching in mysql file

Tags: mysql, search, find

I'm looking for a script (batch file) that could find text from one file in another and report back if that text is found.

for example:

**file 1** would hold a bunch of search strings.

```
find this
find that
find me
find anything
```

**file 2** would be a `.sql` file (the file we are searching)

**file 3** would possibly hold the search string that was found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time now.

Comment: "looking for a solution" & what have you found so far? This is not a script-writing service, though as a community we are happy to help you at the point at which you are stuck writing your own.

Comment: What OS are you on? As you said batch file it's possibly windows? What is your actual goal? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: im on windows 7 and yes i know this is not a script writing service. thanks for your help !

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like a `for` loop.

Something like this:

```
for STRING in `cat file1`
do
grep $STRING file2 >> file3
done
```

What this is doing is typing out the contents of file1. For every line in that file, it is searching file2 for that string and outputting the results to file3.

Comment: `grep` actually has a [`-f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-pattern-from-file) switch to directly read file 1.

Comment: @Seth, you're right. How did I miss that?

Comment: I don't know! :-P Probably because you knew your solution by heart instead of looking at the man page.

Comment: This is awesum and thanks, unfortunatly im using windows. I have found some scripts and modified them to find strings etc, im just struggling (the usual can see the wood through the trees) :-{

Answer (score 0):

whoops forgot to add the code.

```
type nul > results.txt
call :ReadFile < searchtext.txt
goto :EOF

:ReadFile
set /P line=
echo %line%
if "%line%" neq "end" goto FindText
goto EOF

:FindText
findstr /c "%line%" file.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo %line% - found >>results.txt
goto ReadFile
:notfound
echo %line% - notfound >>results.txt
goto readFile

:EOF
exit /B
```

Explanation:

results.txt holds the results of the searches
searchtext.txt holds the search terms and is ended by the word end (change to suit)
file.txt is the file you are going to search

This code outputs into the results.txt file the text being searched for and the result found or notfound.

Hope this helps someone looking for help in this area.